# How can I prevent settings from syncing when using VS Code's Settings Sync feature?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, account

I have VS Code on 2 computers, Mac and PC. I sync settings using my GitHub Account.

But I want to change a couple of settings locally, so they don't copy over to the other computer, where would I change the setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `settingsSync.ignoredSettings` to your settings.json like this:

```
"settingsSync.ignoredSettings": [
    "phpserver.phpPath",
    "remote.SSH.configFile",
    "abapfs.remote"
],
```

Whatever setting you put there, will not be synced.

You can search for "sync setting" in the settings for example, it will display a link to your settings.json file:
[image: settingsSync.ignoredSettings in vscode]